# Hibernate with notation. Add autoincrement in primary key column in postgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4sJ9.png)

And UsersTbEntity class:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "users_tb", schema = "public", catalog = "sbth")
public class UsersTbEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "jpaSequence", sequenceName = "users_tb_user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jpaSequence")
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private int userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private boolean married;
    private String profile;
    private java.util.Date regDate;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 40)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 40)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false, length = 40)
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "married", nullable = false)
    public boolean isMarried() {
        return married;
    }

    public void setMarried(boolean married) {
        this.married = married;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "profile", nullable = false, length = 40)
    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public void setProfile(String profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "reg_date", nullable = true)
    public java.util.Date getRegDate() {
        return regDate;
    }

    public void setRegDate(java.util.Date regDate) {
        this.regDate = regDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UsersTbEntity that = (UsersTbEntity) o;

        if (userId != that.userId) return false;
        if (married != that.married) return false;
        if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null) return false;
        if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null) return false;
        if (gender != null ? !gender.equals(that.gender) : that.gender != null) return false;
        if (profile != null ? !profile.equals(that.profile) : that.profile != null) return false;
        if (regDate != null ? !regDate.equals(that.regDate) : that.regDate != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = userId;
        result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (gender != null ? gender.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (married ? 1 : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (profile != null ? profile.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (regDate != null ? regDate.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I want auto increment table field user_id. But always insert '0' id. And at second insertion I get a error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_tb_pkey"
  Detail: Key (user_id)=(0) already exists.
```

Also I tryed:

```
strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
```

then I get error at session.save(entity):org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationEx‌​ception: ids for this class must be manually assigned beforeQuery calling save().

Answer (score 0):

Modify Like This,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public  Integer getUserId;
// Remaining variables

public Integer getUserId() {
    return getUserId;
}
```

Comment: Error at session.save(entity):org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned beforeQuery calling save().

Comment: Here you are using sequence instead of auto generation.You can remove and try only using auto generation. The second thing if we using the model class, commonly implementing serializable interface. Because object mapping is done by serialization (ORM working).May be it is also a reason. The third thing we have to consider is properly implementing POJO model class. Means, with proper constructor to class. I already added my class using the same method. So you can modify your sequence and try using this simple manner.It will work.No need to implement complex.

Comment: I try different notations. It seem that hibernate not recognized or not mentioned annotation at all. The same behavior if SEQUENCE, AUTO or without notation, even if without @Id - just always try insert line with id 0.

Answer (score 0):

I very unattentive. I forgot remove string   in generated config file hibernate.cfg.xml. But after appear another problem - ERROR: column "firstname" of relation "users_tb" does not exist. My code not contain "firstname" at all! Ok - ALTER TABLE users_tb RENAME COLUMN firs_name TO firstname, and other columns also. 
All works with strategy = GenerationType.AUTO.